# java boolean array with size from user input

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I am prompting the user to enter binary digits as a `String`. I am trying to declare and instantiate an array of `boolean` elements. The array should be equal to the number of digits in the `String` entered by user. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here but am thinking I need to use the `String` `length()` method?

```
public class Binary {

    public static void main ( String [] args ) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter some binary digits > ");
        String value = scan.nextLine();

        boolean [] booleanArray = new boolean [value];
    }
}
```

Comment: `new boolean[value.length()]`

Comment: your value variable is a string, but array declaration must take an int as length, @Gendarme +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Binary {

    public static void main ( String [] args ) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter some binary digits > ");
        String value = scan.nextLine();


        boolean [] booleanArray = new boolean [value.length()];
        //note that initially the values stored in the array are all false
    }
}
```